# Spark DataFrame nulls to Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When importing data from a MS SQL database, there is the potential for null values. In Spark, DataFrames are able to handle the null values. But when I try to convert the DataFrame to a strongly typed Dataset, I receive encoder errors.

Here's a simple example:

```
case class optionTest(var a: Option[Int], var b: Option[Int])

object testObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(input)).toDF()

    val df2 = Seq((1, 3), (3, Option(null)))
                 .toDF("a", "b")
                 .as[optionTest]

    df2.show()
  }
}
```

Here is the error for this case:

```
No Encoder found for Any
- field (class: "java.lang.Object", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Any
- field (class: "java.lang.Object", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
```

What is the recommended approach to handle nullable values when creating a Dataset from a DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your Dataframe doesn't match your case class.

Your first pair is an `(Int, Int)`, and your second is an `(Int, Option[Null])`.

The easy thing to note is that if you want to represent an `Option[Int]`, the value will be either `Some(3)`, for example, or `None` for an absent value.

The tricky thing to note is that in Scala `Int` is a subclass of `AnyVal` while nullable references, which should be almost nonexistent in the Scala code you write, are on the `AnyRef` side of the Scala object hierarchy.

Because you have a bunch of objects that are all over the Scala object model, Spark has to treat your data as `Any`, the superclass of everything. There is no encoder that can handle that.

So with all that said, your data would have to look like this:

`val df2 = Seq((Some(1), Some(3)), (Some(3), None))`

As a side note, your case class should look like this:

`case class OptionTest(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int])`

Comment: This is helpful, but how then would you handle a null value in a DataFrame when going to a Dataset?

Comment: Funny you should ask. I [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43147122/1347281) earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to use `Option` you have to use it for all records. You should also use `None` instead of `Option(null)`:

```
Seq((1, Some(3)), (3, None)).toDF("a", "b").as[optionTest]
```