# Spark dataset reduce with null values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm creating data frame with this code:

```
  val data = List(
    List(444.1235D),
    List(67.5335D),
    List(69.5335D),
    List(677.5335D),
    List(47.5335D),
    List(null)
  )

  val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data).map(Row.fromSeq(_))
  val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("value", DataTypes.DoubleType, true)
  ))

  val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Then I apply my udf to it:

```
val multip: Dataset[Double] = df.select(doubleUdf(df("value"))).as[Double]
```

and then I'm trying to use reduce on this dataset:

```
val multipl = multip.reduce(_ * _)
```

And here I got 0.0 as a result. 
Also I tried to filter nulls out

```
val multipl = multip.filter(_ != null).reduce(_ * _)
```

with the same result.
If I remove null value from data everything works as it should. How can I make reduce work with null values?

My udf is defined like this:

```
val doubleUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf((v: Any) => Try(v.toString.toDouble).toOption)
```

Comment: What is doubleUdf defined as.

Comment: @JustinPihony I've added it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer with a strong assumption that your doubleUdf function converts values to doubles, and rather than using an Option wrapper for nulls you are turning nulls into 0.0. So, if you want to keep the logic to drop nulls, then filter BEFORE anything else:

```
df.na.drop.select(doubleUdf(df("value"))).as[Double]
```

Comment: Actually my udf returns Option as recommended here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357164/sparksql-how-to-deal-with-null-values-in-user-defined-function[/link] Added it to the question

Comment: Up-voted, but `select(doubleUdf(df("value")))` is completely superfluous here. Data is already a `DoubleType`, and if it wasn't it would be better to suggest a `cast`, don't you think?

Comment: It's just example. This function suppose to work for other data types

Answer (score 2):

First, I would ask why you are even dealing with `null` at all. I would evaluate the way I'm reading the data to ensure that doesn't happen.

Then I would note you can eliminate the `null` from your in-memory `List` before you even get to the RDD level like this for example:

`data.flatMap(Option(_)).flatten`

But if you must deal with `null` at the RDD level, you have options (no pun intended):

`sparkContext.parallelize(data).filter(!_.contains(null))`

or

`sparkContext.parallelize(data).map(_.flatMap(Option(_))).filter(_.nonEmpty)`

I prefer the latter. I don't like looking at `null` in Scala code.

I would stay away from a UDF-based solution since Spark can't optimize UDFs, and it is a shame to lose Spark's optimization capabilities over something as lame as `null`.